# Scala Lift MongoDB - Update MongoJsonObjectListField Compilation Error

Tags: json, scala, mongodb, lift

I have the following:

```
def saveAnnotations(annotation: String) = {

    var json = parse(annotation)
    var data: List[AnnotationData] = json.extract[List[AnnotationData]]

    Presentation.update(

        ("room" -> "demo-room"), 
        ("$set" -> ("annotation" -> data))

    )

}
```

Where the var "annotation" is a json object array string, e.g

```
[{"key": "val"},{"key": "val"}]
```

The field "annotation" is a MongoJsonObjectListField

When compiling I'm recieving the following error:

```
No implicit view available from (String, List[code.snippet.AnnotationData]) => 
net.liftweb.json.package.JValue.("$set" -> ("annotation" -> data))
                                        ^
```

I'm sure something simple is missing, any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**

I've just noticed that it compiles if I do:

```
Presentation.update(

    ("room" -> "demo-room"), 
    ("$set" -> ("annotation" -> ""))

)
```

However this obviously sets the annotation field value to an empty string, how would I force the annotation field to be overwritten with the json object array in the data var?